# Find an address beginning by in js

Tags: javascript

I have the following type of url in my page:

```
http://fruit.forest.com/add?map&center=45.509651,-73.551216&zoom=14
```

How can I find this address in all my code and how can I find the lat and lng coordinates ?

---

I tried:

```
var mapSrc = $(pageDetailsSecond); // My source page code
var mapData = new RegExp('center=(\\d+\\.?\\d*),(-?\\d+\\.?\\d*)').exec(mapSrc);

// Latitude
var card_Latitude = mapData[1];

// Longitude
var card_Longitude = mapData[2];
```

But I have the error: `TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'mapData[1]')`

Thanks.

Comment: try this https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561

Comment: what is mapSrc? Is it a jquery object? If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex = /center=(-?\d+\.\d+),(-?\d+\.\d+)/;
var result = regex.exec("http://fruit.forest.com/add?map&center=45.509651,-73.551216&zoom=14")
result
["http://fruit.forest.com/add?map&center=45.509651,-73.551216", "45.509651", "-73.551216"]
```